# AngularJS: Get Data From Controller In Service

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

There's a plethora of information regarding getting data from a service and using it in the controller, but I have scoured the internet and found no examples of or explanations on how to do this. If I have a basic controller:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myObject = [
    {
      x = 1;
      y = 2;
    },
    {
      x = 3;
      y = 4;
  }]
});
```

I would like to write a service that would take the object "myObject" from the controller, alter the object, and send it back to the controller. I understand how to write services and get the information TO a controller, but how can a service access the object "myObject"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to :

1) Create the service and the function which modifies the data.
3) Inject the service in your controller.
4) Call your service's function.

Check out this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tvyk0a3n/1/) I've wrote down for you.

You've got the controller:

```
.controller("MyController",function($scope, ModifyDataService) {
  $scope.data = "foo";
  $scope.dataModified = null;
  $scope.modifyData = function() {
        $scope.dataModified = ModifyDataService($scope.data);
    }
})
```

And the service which modifies the data:

```
.service("ModifyDataService", function() {
    return function(data) {
        /** Reverse String **/
    if(typeof data !== 'string') throw 'Data must be string';
    return Array.from(data).reverse().join("");
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If your use case just involves altering an object, then perhaps a service method is the answer.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.myObject = [{
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
  }, {
    x = 3;
    y = 4;
  }];

  /* Option 1, transform object in place. */
  myService.changeObject( $scope.myObject ); 

  /* Option 2, replace object. */
  $scope.myObject = myService.changeObject( $scope.myObject );
});
```